# Replace space in a specific column with a character

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in format

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1+A2)
C  (A1 A2)
D  (!(A1 A2) B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2) A3 A4)
G  ((A1 A2)+(A3 A4))
```

I want output as

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1+A2)
C  (A1&A2)
D  (!(A1&A2)&B1
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2)&A3&A4)
G  ((A1&A2)+(A3&A4))
```

So whenever there is space in column2 I want it to get replaced with `&`
I tried

```
sed 's/ /&/2' file
```

But there is no change
I also tried

```
awk -F' ' '{if($2==" ")$2="&";}1' file
```

This also has no change getting back input file only.

Comment: Think about it - how could $2 or any other field ever be a blank char (`$2==" "`) when you've set the field separator to a blank char (`-F' '`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this `awk` with 2 spaces as input/output field separator:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="  "} {gsub(/ +/, "\\&", $2)} 1' file

A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1+A2)
C  (A1&A2)
D  (!(A1&A2)&B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2)&A3&A4)
G  ((A1&A2)+(A3&A4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can harness `sed` for this task following way:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1\&\2/g'
```

gives for input

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1+A2)
C  (A1 A2)
D  (!(A1 A2) B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2) A3 A4)
G  ((A1 A2)+(A3 A4))
```

output

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1+A2)
C  (A1&A2)
D  (!(A1&A2)&B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2)&A3&A4)
G  ((A1&A2)+(A3&A4))
```

Explanation: I used capturing groups here, 1st is any character but space, 2nd is also any character but space and there is space between them, such match is replaced by content of 1st group (`\1`) followed by & (`\&`) followed by content of 2nd group (`\2`). Note that we want multiple replacements, hence `g`. Disclaimer: this solution assumes there are not leading or trailing spaces in your input.